# WooCommerce hide country from shiping dropdown if language is

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

I have this function for hiding some shipping countries from the WooCommerce dropdown in the Checkout based on WPML language that is currenly active.

This code seems to be working but not 100%. This is my code so far:

```
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'nl') { 
    function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) 
    {
        unset($country["DE"]);
        unset($country["AT"]);
        return $country; 
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
}
```

This is almost working but the labels in the dropdown are empty, not gone completely.
See this screenshot: [Empty labels country dropdown][1]

Anybody knows how I can remove the empty labels too?
[1]: https://imgur.com/a/mUTpVar

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove the entries, you should not only unset the countries but also reindex the array after unsetting.

```
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'nl') { 
    function woo_remove_specific_country($countries) 
    {
        $countries_to_remove = array("DE", "AT");

        foreach ($countries_to_remove as $country_code) {
            if (isset($countries[$country_code])) {
                unset($countries[$country_code]);
            }
        }

        $countries = array_values($countries);

        return $countries; 
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1);
}
```

This should resolve the issue of empty labels in the country dropdown. Make sure to replace "**DE**" and "**AT**" with the actual country codes you want to remove. Additionally let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Tried this too, but all countries are gone in the checkout so this isn't working too:(

Answer (score 0):

Use always the IF statement inside your function (and disable for backend)…
Try the following revised code:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_countries', 'conditionally_remove_specific_country', 10, 1);
function conditionally_remove_specific_country( $country ) 
{
    if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE !== 'nl' || is_admin() ) {
        return $country;
    }

    if ( isset($country["DE"]) ) {
        unset($country["DE"]);
    }

    if ( isset($country["AT"]) ) {
        unset($country["AT"]);
    }
    return $country; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried this but the result is the same. DE and AT are removed but the labels are blank and stil in the dropdown. https://imgur.com/a/GLlzGDl, see this screenshot. Any ideas on this?

Comment: This is strange, as I don't get this issue on my local test website (using Storefront theme).